# Solr facet sum instead of count

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm new to Solr and I'm interested in implementing a special facet.

Sample documents:

```
{ hostname: google.com, time_spent: 100 }
{ hostname: facebook.com, time_spent: 10 }
{ hostname: google.com, time_spent: 30 }
{ hostname: reddit.com, time_spent: 20 }
...
```

I would like to return a facet with the following structure:

```
{ google.com: 130, reddit.com: 20, facebook.com: 10 }
```

Although solr return values are much more verbose than this, the important point is how the "counts" for the facets are the sum of the time_spent values for the documents rather than the actual count of the documents matching the facet.

### Idea #1:

I could use a pivot:

```
q:*:*
&facet=true
&facet.pivot=hostname,time_spent
```

However, this returns the counts of all the unique time spent values for every unique hostname. I could sum this up in my application manually, but this seems wasteful.

### Idea #2

I could use the stats module:

```
q:*:*
&stats=true
&stats.field=time_spent
&stats.facet=hostname
```

However, this has two issues. First, the returned results contain *all* the hostnames. This is really problematic as my dataset has over 1m hostnames. Further, the returned results are unsorted - I need to render the hostnames in order of descending total time spent.

Your help with this would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: At first I was tempted to direct you to [the StatsComponent](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component) in conjunction with its' facet. But that one would iterate over _all_ your 1m hostnames.

Comment: Take a look into heliosearch by Yonik Seely: http://heliosearch.org/solr-facet-functions/

Comment: Unfortunately, heliosearch is not an option for me - I'm stuck on solr.

Comment: I'm in the same dilemma right now. If only stats.facet supports all  facet options (specially facet.limit and facet.sort)...

Comment: There is support for this now starting in Solr 5.1 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7214

Answer (score 7):

With Solr >=5.1, this is possible:

> Facet Sorting
>
> The default sort for a field or terms facet is by bucket count
>   descending. We can optionally sort ascending or descending by any
>   facet function that appears in each bucket. For example, if we wanted
>   to find the top buckets by average price, then we would add sort:"x
>   desc" to the previous facet request:
>
> ```
> $ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/query -d 'q=*:*&
>  json.facet={
>    categories:{
>      type : terms,
>      field : cat,
>      sort : "x desc",   // can also use sort:{x:desc}
>      facet:{
>        x : "avg(price)",
>        y : "sum(price)"
>      }
>    }
>  }
> '
> ```

See Yonik's Blog: http://yonik.com/solr-facet-functions/

For your use case this would be:

```
json.facet={
  hostname_time:{
    type: terms,
    field: hostname,
    sort: "time_total desc",
    facet:{
      time_total: "sum(time_spent)",
    }
  }
}
```

Calling `sum()` in nested facets worked for us only in 6.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is an aggregation component, but be aware that solr is a full text search engine and not the database.

So, answer of your question is , go with idea#1. Otherwise you should have used Elastics Search or MongoDB or even Redis which are equipped with such aggregation components.

Comment: i agree with you solr is a search engine, if you want to aggregate you could develop it or use others engines

Comment: It is a myth still. Solr is a search first nosql. We certainly use it more as nosql